# matplotlib Basemap Fundamental Lune

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to recreate this projection using matplotlib [Fundamental Lune Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPlYo.jpg). The reference material associated with this specific projection is here, [Carl Tape Moment Tensors](http://www.giseis.alaska.edu/input/carl/research/beachball.html)

The geophysics behind the plot isn't crucial, but essentially its a projection between longitudes of -30 and 30 degrees and latitudes -90 to 90.  I've thought that Basemap might be a good way of creating the projection, but I cannot seem to figure out how to only show this fundamental lune section.  Here is what I've been playing around with,but it still shows the entire globe:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(
        resolution='l',     # coastline resolution, can be 'l' (low), 'h'
        projection='hammer', # Hammer projection
        lat_ts=0,          # latitude of true scale
        lon_0=0,          # longitude of the plotting domain center
        lat_0=0)           # latitude of the plotting domain center

# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,90.,10.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-30.,31.,10.))
ax = plt.gca()
plt.show()
```

Can anybody offer some guidance or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Basemap, I believe the Hammer projection is "global", meaning that it doesn't take extent inputs so it makes sense the entire globe would always show. As of 2022 Basemap is heavily deprecated / not supported.

I was able to make the plot you want using [Cartopy](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/) instead.  The following code produces image below and on the left, with some demo data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.path as mpath

# The Sinusoidal projection was added to Cartopy in version 0.14
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.Sinusoidal())

# Here I define a matplotlib Path object to use as the boundary
outlinex = np.concatenate([[-30],np.tile(-30,180), np.tile(30,180),[-30]])
outliney = np.concatenate([[-90],np.arange(-90,90),np.arange(89,-91,-1),[-90]])
outlinecodes = np.array([mpath.Path.MOVETO]+[mpath.Path.LINETO]*360+[mpath.Path.MOVETO])
outlinepath = mpath.Path(np.column_stack([outlinex[::-1], outliney[::-1]]), outlinecodes[::-1])

# For good measure, plot some data
ax.plot(np.arange(-10,25), np.linspace(80,45,35), transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.plot(np.tile(25,91),np.arange(45,-46,-1), transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

# Plot gridlines and set the boundary
ax.gridlines(xlocs=np.arange(-30,31,10), ylocs=np.arange(-90,91,45))
ax.set_boundary(outlinepath, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

# The plotting will have automatically set the extents, so set them to what we want
ax.set_extent((-30,30,-90,90))

plt.show()
```

Note, that if you omit the `set_boundary` elements and just use the `set_extent`, you'll get the image on the right, rather than the image on the left.

[image: lune plot with correct boundary]   [image: lune plot with squared boundary]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. It looks like it might work